# How can padding be disambiguated from data, when encrypting using a block cipher?

Tags: encryption, block-cipher, padding

> How can padding be disambiguated from data, when encrypting using a block cipher?

I'm by no means an expert in cryptography, but rather a programmer with a keen interest.

Suppose, I've `X` bytes of data, message `M`, that I want to encrypt using an `N`-byte block cipher, where `N >> X`.

How can `M` be padded using `N-X` bytes of padding `O`, such that there would be no ambiguity between decrypting the padded message `M´` and the (concatenated) message `M|O`?

How is this done in practice? Normally, when encrypting using a block cipher, I don't see a header being output describing the original length of the message `M`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual padding for block ciphers ("PKCS#7 padding") is not a sequence of zeroes, but a sequence of `P = N - (X % N)` bytes each with value `P`.

If the message is a multiple of the block size, then a full block of padding is added (where each byte value is the block size).

For example, is the message is 15-byte long and the block size is 16 bytes, than one byte of padding will be added, and the value of the byte is `1`. If the message is 14-byte long, two bytes with value `2` will be added. If the message is 16-byte long, sixteen bytes with value `16` will be added.

With these rules, the padding is unambiguous.

Comment: Thanks. But why `M|1`? And what if the block size is >= 256 bits :-) ? Is your padding scheme the one used for all block ciphers, like AES?

Comment: I'm assuming there needs to be 1 byte of padding, thus that padding byte will have value 1. Yes, that doesn't work for block sizes larger than 256 bytes, but most block ciphers have 16-byte block sizes. And yes, this is the [PKCS#7 padding, also called PKCS#5 padding](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9043/what-is-the-difference-between-pkcs5-padding-and-pkcs7-padding)

Comment: Ohh, nice - I was assuming `N-X` bytes of padding, nvm. Is the padding scheme for AES (512 bits) similar?

Comment: @Shuzheng it's not exactly `N-X`, it's the smaller number larger than zero that makes the result size a multiple of the block size. AES has 128-bit block size (e.g. 16 bytes), and it indeed works as described

Comment: Yes, but here `N` is the block size in bytes, while `X` is the length of the message to be encrypted. Then indeed, `N-X` bytes of padding is needed, right? What do you mean by "it's the smaller number larger than..."?

Comment: @Shuzheng Sorry, I just realized that you specified that the block size is larger than the message. Otherwise, if `N` is 16 and `X` is 31, then `N-X=-15` but 1 byte of padding is needed. The size of the padding is basically `N - (X % N)`.

Comment: Ahh, thanks for clarifying this.

Comment: Remember, one can use also, M100...000