# OpenSSL: How to maintain padding from encryption after decryption?

Tags: encryption, padding, decryption

One of my professors mentioned in class that there is a way of using PKCS#7 padding to have the padding persistent after decryption.

For example, if I encrypt a 20-byte file using

```
openssl enc -aes-128-ecb -in input.txt -out encrypted.txt -K 0123456789 -v
```

I obviously get the padded difference of:

```
bytes read   :       20
bytes written:       32
```

So 12 bytes of padding was added.

After decryption of the file, I want the padding to remain.

The only method I could think of was making the bytes in the original `input.txt` file the same character that PKCS#7 uses to pad, so that when it's time to unpad, it doesn't know what to unpad.  I haven't been able to find exactly which character it uses, or if it's not a character.  I've read some about the standard [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)) and [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652#section-6.3), but with no real luck.

I'm still reading on it, but I haven't had any eureka moments yet.

An example of what I'm looking for would be if I gave it a 4-byte file such as:

```
AAAA
```

And it encrypted it, but added 12 bytes of C at the end, I'd want the decrypted file to be:

```
AAAACCCCCCCCCCCC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In OpenSSL there is an `-nopad` option. If you don't want the OpenSSL removing the padding bytes, add the `-nopad` option.

```
openssl enc -d  -nopad -aes-128-ecb -in  encrypted.txt -K 0123456789 -v -out decrypted.txt
```

Note that you cannot see as `C` because the OpenSSL doesn't print in hex.

To see in hex you can use `xxd` command

```
 xxd -r decrypted.txt

00000000: 3132 3334 3534 3334 3837 3433 3733 3838  1234543487437388
00000010: 3431 3431 3433 3436 410a 0606 0606 0606  41414346A.......
```

See, the 6 `06` and the plaintext was

```
123454348743738841414346A
```

---

**Note:** Note: In PKCS#7 padding with 128-bit block cipher we don't see `C`s, but we have `0C, 1C,2C,3C,4C,5C,6C,7C`. What you mention is PKCS#5. See the difference in [What is the difference between PKCS#5 padding and PKCS#7 padding](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/9043/18298)

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful.  After decrypting with the -nopad option it did retain the padding.  The padding is showing as 12 `^L`'s which makes sense.

Comment: For some reason xxd can't read the decrypted text.  The error message makes me think it's because the decrypted text isn't in hex anymore.

Comment: I know that `^M` is a newline character from windows, but I'm not familiar with `^L`

Comment: Can you try 'xxd -b'